# Implement cos in Java without Math.cos function

Tags: java, trigonometry

I'm trying to calculate cosine without using the `Math.cos()` function. I know how it is done in theory by using the taylor series, but I always get wrong results. Here is my code:

```
public static final double PI = Math.PI;

public int calcFakultaet(int x)
    {
    int sum = 1;
    for (int i = sum; i <= x; i++)
        {
        sum *= i;
        }
    return sum;
    }

public double pow(double x, double y)
    {
    if (y == 0) return 1;

    double erg = x;
    for (int i = 1; i < y; i++)
        {
        erg *= x;
        }
    return erg;
    }

public double toRadians(double x)
    {
    return x * PI / 180;
    }

public double calcCos(double x)
    {
    if (x > (2 * PI)) x = this.toRadians(x);
    double erg = 0.0;
    double tmp = 1.0;
    double sign = -1.0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 12; i+=2)
        {
        int fak = this.calcFak(i);
        tmp = sign * this.pow(x, i) / fak;
        sign *= -1.0;
        erg += -tmp;
        }

    return erg
    }
```

I would be very happy if anyone could help me!

Comment: I have no idea what approach you are using, but the loop `for (int i = 1; i < border; i += 2)` runs exactly 3 times no matter the input. Is that the desired behavior?

Comment: Yes, the task I got included to run until the border 2 times pi, sorry I forgot to include this explanation into my intro. The reason is that the taylor series gets too inaccurate after 2 times pi.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misunderstood the question. 2*Pi is a full circle, so there is no point in doing the calculation for values outside the range 0...2*Pi radians. You could reject inputs outside that range, but it is easy to take the input value mod 2*Pi and use that.

Each cosine calculation should convert from degrees to radians, then run the Taylor series loop N times using that angle as the input 'x'. The value of N is up to you. More iterations will produce more accurate results until you hit the limits of double precision arithmetic. The person who set the task may have given instructions on that.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I just edited my post, but it still does not work. Any idea?

Comment: I think you are asking us to debug your program for you. Please explain exactly what does not work. We are happy to help you, but you need to give us a start.